# I'm attempting a breakdown of a certificate of analysis

Tags: arithmetic

THCa=3.43%
CBDa=14.77%
CBD =0.31%
CBGa=0.50%

Total CBD=CBDa*0.877+CBD;LOQ

Using the equation provided by the lab I have been unable to reach the same answer of 13.26% total CBD %. I am assuming the semicolon is simply stating that the CBD% only depends on the limit of quantintation (0.10) established by the lab . The raised asterisk is used to denote the variables or peramiters its separating . Ive given myself almost an hour of attempts trying to reverse engineer , understand symbols and I'm missing something simple I'm sure . That being said Ive given respect to the process of truly understanding how to properly read a COA unfortunately time has out weighed my learning curve these days . Any insight is greatly appreciated thanks !